# Eclipse Plugin Development Default Key Bindings: What are the key codes for special keys (Shift, Alt, etc.)?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin and therefore defining some key bindings. From [this resource](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommandsKeybindings/article.html) I know that the control key is denoted by the code `M1`.

Where can I find a table that maps all special keys to their key code, in particular Shift, Alt, Caps Lock and Enter?

Comment: The Eclipse Help documentation of the org.eclipse.ui.bindings extension point covers all this. Note that on macOS M1 is ⌘ not Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_bindings.html):

> The recognized modifiers keys are M1, M2, M3, M4, ALT, COMMAND, CTRL, and SHIFT. The "M" modifier keys are a platform-independent way of representing keys, and these are generally preferred. M1 is the COMMAND key on MacOS X, and the CTRL key on most other platforms. M2 is the SHIFT key. M3 is the Option key on MacOS X, and the ALT key on most other platforms. M4 is the CTRL key on MacOS X, and is undefined on other platforms.